# Sr no as per financial year from april to march in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have job_no with other fields in my database, I need to identify the date and according to that date job no should be generated automatically. The date criteria  is financial year April to March.
If financial year change, job no should start from 1 else continue.

What can I do in this situation?

I'm using php and mysql.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function in `php` that check for the date and month so that you get to know which financial year a date lies. In that function you can check the financial year of current date and according to that either continue with the last incremented value, or restart the value from 1.

The function definition is something like:

```
if (date('m') > 3) {
    $year = date('Y') +1;
}
else {
    $year = $date('Y');
}
```

or

```
if (date('m') > 3) {
    $year = date('Y')."-".(date('Y') +1);
}
else {
    $year = (date('Y')-1)."-".date('Y');
}
```

Comment: Sir I know that I'll need to make a function for that, but I can not Imagine the logic or function for that.